# Parsing complex json in flutter List problems

Tags: java, json, flutter, dart

I am creating an app and i get these json

```
    {
  "countries": [
    {
      "Mainland_China": {
        "confirmed": 77660,
        "deaths": 2663,
        "recovered": 27650
      },
      "Thailand": {
        "confirmed": 37,
        "deaths": 0,
        "recovered": 22
}
```

so i used https://app.quicktype.io/ to make the models and trow me this

```
import 'dart:convert';

Corona2 corona2FromJson(str) => Corona2.fromJson(json.decode(str));



class Corona2 {
    List<Map<String, Country>> countries;
    String dt;
    double ts;

    Corona2({
        this.countries,
        this.dt,
        this.ts,
    });

    factory Corona2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Corona2(
        countries: List<Map<String, Country>>.from(json["countries"].map((x) => Map.from(x).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Country>(k, Country.fromJson(v))))),
        dt: json["dt"],
        ts: json["ts"],
    );

}

class Country {
    int confirmed;
    int deaths;
    int recovered;

    Country({
        this.confirmed,
        this.deaths,
        this.recovered,
    });

    factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
        confirmed: json["confirmed"],
        deaths: json["deaths"],
        recovered: json["recovered"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "confirmed": confirmed,
        "deaths": deaths,
        "recovered": recovered,
    };
}
```

but when i call it in the future as this

```
  Future<Corona2> cargarPaises() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/current_list');

        return corona2FromJson(response.body);
```

I got an error that say

```
type 'Corona2' is not a subtype of type 'List<Corona2>'
```

i have tried everyting tried to make a list in the models i cant figure out how to fix it i have like 1 week with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I fix some issues, also add types and you can debug for yourself.
In your implementation you have multiple problems, but the main is that trying using `Map` as `List`.
Also I suggest to improve your json file and move `Countries` upper in hierarchy. After that you can remove `[0]` in `map['countries'][0]`.
But it definitely parsable json and example below show this.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Corona2> testMethod() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://covid2019-api.herokuapp.com/current_list');

  return Corona2.fromJson(json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
}

class Corona2 {
  Corona2({this.countries, this.dt, this.ts});
  Corona2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map['countries'] != null) {
      countries = <Country>[];
      final remoteCountries = map['countries'][0] as Map;
      remoteCountries.forEach((v, e) {
        countries.add(Country.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>));
      });
    }
    dt = map['dt'] as String;
    ts = map['ts'] as double;
  }

  List<Country> countries;
  String dt;
  double ts;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (countries != null) {
      data['countries'] = countries.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['dt'] = dt;
    data['ts'] = ts;
    return data;
  }
}

class Country {
  Country({
    this.confirmed,
    this.deaths,
    this.recovered,
  });

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
        confirmed: json["confirmed"] as int,
        deaths: json["deaths"] as int,
        recovered: json["recovered"] as int,
      );

  int confirmed;
  int deaths;
  int recovered;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "confirmed": confirmed,
        "deaths": deaths,
        "recovered": recovered,
      };
}
```

call testMethod to get Corona2 result

Answer (score 0):

[image]Maybe what I see from you code is when you call the method cargarPaises() in that you have made a get request and according to you model class you have created from QuickType.io. But when you pass the response to this

```
final corona2 = corona2FromJson(response.body);
```

so you are getting the single Corona2 object and not the List[Corona2].

I am little bit confused what do want achieve, Do you want the list countries to be parsed in the list.

so Later i was working on it i have made it working just check the below code :

Below json i have taken locally and parsed:

```
{
    "countries": [{
        "Mainland_China": {
            "confirmed": 78065,
            "deaths": 2715,
            "recovered": 30053
        },
        "Thailand": {
            "confirmed": 40,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 22
        },
        "Japan": {
            "confirmed": 189,
            "deaths": 2,
            "recovered": 22
        },
        "South_Korea": {
            "confirmed": 1261,
            "deaths": 12,
            "recovered": 22
        },
        "Taiwan": {
            "confirmed": 32,
            "deaths": 1,
            "recovered": 5
        },
        "US": {
            "confirmed": 59,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 6
        },
        "Macau": {
            "confirmed": 10,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 7
        },
        "Hong_Kong": {
            "confirmed": 91,
            "deaths": 2,
            "recovered": 24
        },
        "Singapore": {
            "confirmed": 93,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 62
        },
        "Vietnam": {
            "confirmed": 16,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 16
        },
        "France": {
            "confirmed": 18,
            "deaths": 2,
            "recovered": 11
        },
        "Nepal": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "Malaysia": {
            "confirmed": 22,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 18
        },
        "Canada": {
            "confirmed": 11,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 3
        },
        "Australia": {
            "confirmed": 22,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 11
        },
        "Cambodia": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "Sri_Lanka": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "Germany": {
            "confirmed": 27,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 15
        },
        "Finland": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "United_Arab_Emirates": {
            "confirmed": 13,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 4
        },
        "Philippines": {
            "confirmed": 3,
            "deaths": 1,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "India": {
            "confirmed": 3,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 3
        },
        "Italy": {
            "confirmed": 453,
            "deaths": 12,
            "recovered": 3
        },
        "UK": {
            "confirmed": 13,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 8
        },
        "Russia": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 2
        },
        "Sweden": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Spain": {
            "confirmed": 13,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 2
        },
        "Belgium": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 1
        },
        "Others": {
            "confirmed": 705,
            "deaths": 4,
            "recovered": 10
        },
        "Egypt": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Iran": {
            "confirmed": 139,
            "deaths": 19,
            "recovered": 49
        },
        "Lebanon": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Iraq": {
            "confirmed": 5,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Oman": {
            "confirmed": 4,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Afghanistan": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Bahrain": {
            "confirmed": 33,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Kuwait": {
            "confirmed": 26,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Algeria": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Croatia": {
            "confirmed": 3,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Switzerland": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Austria": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Israel": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Pakistan": {
            "confirmed": 2,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Brazil": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Georgia": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Greece": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "North_Macedonia": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Norway": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        },
        "Romania": {
            "confirmed": 1,
            "deaths": 0,
            "recovered": 0
        }
    }],
    "dt": "2/26/20",
    "ts": 1582675200.0
}
```

Model class defined for the json :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final corona2 = corona2FromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Corona2 corona2FromJson(String str) => Corona2.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String corona2ToJson(Corona2 data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Corona2 {
    List<Map<String, Country>> countries;
    String dt;
    double ts;

    Corona2({
        this.countries,
        this.dt,
        this.ts,
    });

    factory Corona2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Corona2(
        countries: List<Map<String, Country>>.from(json["countries"].map((x) => Map.from(x).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Country>(k, Country.fromJson(v))))),
        dt: json["dt"],
        ts: json["ts"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "countries": List<dynamic>.from(countries.map((x) => Map.from(x).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())))),
        "dt": dt,
        "ts": ts,
    };
}

class Country {
    int confirmed;
    int deaths;
    int recovered;

    Country({
        this.confirmed,
        this.deaths,
        this.recovered,
    });

    factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
        confirmed: json["confirmed"],
        deaths: json["deaths"],
        recovered: json["recovered"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "confirmed": confirmed,
        "deaths": deaths,
        "recovered": recovered,
    };
}
```

And the main file where the ui interacts with the data :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dummy.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Countries {
  String name;
  String confirmed;
  String deaths;
  String recovered;

  Countries(this.name, this.confirmed, this.deaths, this.recovered);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadImageState createState() => _UploadImageState();
}

class _UploadImageState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<Object> objectList = List();
  List<Countries> countries = List();

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadYourData();
  }

  loadYourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final corona2 = corona2FromJson(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < corona2.countries.length; i++) {
      corona2.countries[i].forEach((key, value) {
        print(value.confirmed.toString());

        countries.add(Countries(key, value.confirmed.toString(),
            value.deaths.toString(), value.recovered.toString()));
      });
    }
    print('This is the coutries data ${countries.length}');

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedFruit;

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: countries.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Card(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Coutrt name :'),
                              Text(countries[index].name)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(' Confirmed :'),
                              Text(countries[index].confirmed)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(' Death:'),
                              Text(countries[index].deaths)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('Recovered:'),
                              Text(countries[index].recovered)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                                        ),
                    ),
                  );
                })),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```